# Discord Bot / aiohttp multiple requests in session using values of the previous respone

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, aiohttp

I have builda discord bot and want replace requests with aiohttp, but i cant get it to work like i does it with requests

```
# code with requests looks like this
import requests
import discord


async def get_skills(url, user, nick):
    debug = client.get_channel(channels[1])

    image = requests.get(url)
    result = requests.post(url, data{'image': image, 'user': user, 'nick': nick})
    await debug.send(result, file=discord.File(image, 'blank.png'))
```

What the function do is taking the url and downloading the image and sending it over to an external server to process informations and sending this json data back.

here the function post the image an the information to a predefined channel

```
import io
import aiohttp
import discord


async def post_image(url, user, nick):
    debug = client.get_channel(channels[1])

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # Get image
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            image = io.BytesIO(await response.read())

        # this works if i send here the image in a channel like:
        # await debug.send(file=discord.File(image, 'test.png'))
        # but befor sending the image i a channel:

        data = aiohttp.FormData()
        data.add_field('file', image)
        data.add_field('user', str(user))
        data.add_field('nick', str(nick))


        # but befor i want to send the image to an api to get json data back
        # and use this as content
        async with session.post(image_host, data=data) as info:
            result = await info.text()

        # sending here dont work, i cant access the image to
        # send data and the image to a channel

        # ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
        await debug.send(result, file=discord.File(image, 'blank.png'))
```

How can i use the image multiple times without downloading it again?